# Calculating set of undirected link neighbors of node p

Tags: python, numpy, graph

Given a graph G we have the score for a pair of nodes(p,q) in G-

[image]

I want to calculate the value of this function where L(p) denotes the set of undirected link neighbors of node p.(C is a constant)

I know how to calculate the out and in link neighbours from the adjacency matric separately which is-

```
    in_nbs = []
    for i in range(self.num_nodes):
       # print type(np.nonzero(a[:, i]))
        in_nbs.append(np.nonzero(a[:, i])[0])
        #column i. This works for undirected and directed graphs

    print in_nbs    

    out_nbs=[]        

    for j in range(self.num_nodes):
        out_nbs.append(np.nonzero(a[j,:])[0])
```

but I wanted to calculate the set of undirected link neighbours directly.The input given to us is an adjacency matrix and the graph type is directed.

Comment: Make the graph undirected by summing the adjacency matrix with its transpose, then compute either your in- or your out-degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paul this is the answer i am getting-   `

```
        a = np.array([  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0] ])        

        a_transpose=np.transpose(a)
        a_undirected=np.add(a,a_transpose)

        self.num_nodes = np.shape(a)[0]
        current_sim = np.eye(self.num_nodes)
        prev_sim = np.zeros(shape=(self.num_nodes, self.num_nodes))

        # Determine the set of In-Neighbors for each node
        nbs = []

        for i in range(self.num_nodes):

            nbs.append(np.nonzero(a_undirected[:, i])[0])
```

output-
[

```
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 4], dtype=int64), array([3], dtype=int64)]
```